# Spring PropertiesFactoryBean that automatically exposes a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's property

Tags: spring

Ideally I'd like to do this from code:

```
@Value("#{aPropertiesFactoryBean.aProperty}")
private String aProperty;
```

Based on a spring configuration where I set up a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and a PropertiesFactoryBean, and just pass the configurer bean as a ref to the bean, and everything that the configurer generates is exposed as a property of the factory bean.

There is a hack to just redefine every property from the Configurer like:

```
<bean id="aPropertiesFactoryBean" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="properties">
      <props>
        <prop key="aProperty">${aProperty}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then every time you add a property to the Configurer, you have to re-expose it with the FactoryBean.  And the punchline is, I want all the management features of the configurer, and also be able to reference the same batch of properties from both the spring xml files, and @Value annotations.

So the two questions:

1. Is there something like this out of the box?
2. It looks like it would be simple to override PropertiesFactoryBean and give it a property for the PlaceholderConfigurer, but the code to actually access the properties would have to involve unwelding the hood through reflection and digging into Spring's internal PropertiesLoaderSupport class.  Is there a less hacky way to do this?

Note, I'm not looking for something that can just quickly get me on my way, the above hack with PropertiesFactoryBean suffices for now.  I'm looking to either find or make a reusable component that I can use to easily manage injectable properties for projects down the road.

Answer (score 3):

I was just thinking about this backwards.  This config does exactly what I want, being able to have properties defined in the xml config, overridable from a properties file, and available as both placeholder properties and injectable values.

```
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- 
   One-stop shopping for properties here. 
   Available as injected values and elsewhere in the spring config. 
  -->
  <bean id="injectableProperties" 
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">         
          <property name="singleton" value="true" />
          <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
          <property name="properties">
            <props>
              <prop key="prop1">value1</prop>
              <prop key="prop2">value2</prop>               
            </props>
          </property>
          <!-- Allow foo.conf to override default properties -->
          <property name="location" value="file:/etc/foo/foo.conf" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Expose the properties so other parts of the spring config can use them -->
  <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    <property name="properties" ref="injectableProperties"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the situation, but you can inject properties without having to define a `PropertiesFactoryBean` by using the syntax:

```
@Value("${my.property}") String myProperty;
```